# App Registration vs Enterprise Applications

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I kind of know (well I think) the difference between them

Enterprise Application - Service account that maps back to an app under app registration.

So, what exactly is app registration outside of just registering your app? What are the API tokens, reply URL's, etc? Are the permissions handled there or through the service account?

I understand that the app maps to a service account within your tenant, so that it can access resources as that service account, but what if another user from a different tenant wants to access your app? Do you create a service account for that user in your tenant? Do they do something on their side? Does that service account somehow map back to the original app it's for?

I guess I'm kind confused on the questions above if someone could please break it down for me

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> but what if another user from a different tenant wants to access your
> app? Do you create a service account for that user in your tenant?

No, a service account for the app (and not user) is created in the user's tenant (it is known as Service Principal in Azure terminology). This happens when a user consents to the app in their tenant. For this, the app must be registered as multi-tenant.

However if you want this external user to access resources associated with your tenant, then you will need to add that external user in your tenant. In that case, the app can be registered as single-tenant (i.e. scoped to your Azure AD only).

> Do they do something on their side?

Kind of yes. They would need to consent to the app.

> Does that service account somehow map back to the original app it's
> for?

That's correct. That service account only works under the constraints specified by the app. For example, if the app has permission to execute Azure Service Management API then this service account is only allowed to do so. The service account cannot add permissions of their own.

You may find this link helpful in understanding more about App Registrations and Service Principals: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav Mantri. I guess I'm a little confused on the following. So, once they consent, a service account is created in the users tenant and that service account is used to access the web app/API? How do you assign permissions to this user then, as in what permissions their allowed to have when accessing the web app/API? I guess I'm under the impression you'd have to create a service account for every client and assign the appropriate permissions, can you clear that up?

Comment: `So, once they consent, a service account is created in the users tenant and that service account is used to access the web app/API?` - That's correct. `How do you assign permissions to this user then, as in what permissions their allowed to have when accessing the web app/API?` - When a Service Principal (SP) is created, you can navigate to that SP in Azure Portal and will assign roles to the users by going under `Users and Group`.

Comment: `I guess I'm under the impression you'd have to create a service account for every client and assign the appropriate permissions, can you clear that up?` - You don't have to manually create a service account, it is automatically created for you when a user consents. Hope this answers your questions.